# Writing a ggplot function to create graphs including multiple datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a standard function to create graphs with specific attributes. I am including 4 datasets on the graph (one geom_line and 3 geom_point), as well as a number of fixed attributes, intercepts and scale limits.

However, when I input the variables in my function, it gets stuck.
This is the function I tried to write:

```
plot_testassess <- function(data1,
                            data2,
                            data3,
                            data4,
                            xvar = "Time",
                            yvar = "Zscore",
                            zvar ="Amplitude"
                           ) {ggplot(data1, aes(.data1[[xvar]], .data1[[yvar]]))+
    geom_line(colour="#85C1E9", size=0.8) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0, color = "black", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 2.5, color = "grey", size = 0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = -1.5, color = "grey", size = 0.5) +
    geom_point(data2, aes(.data2[[xvar]], .data2[[yvar]]), shape=17, colour="#42055B")+ # purple color
    geom_point(data3, aes(.data3[[xvar]], .data3[[yvar]]), shape=17, colour="#BE4A58")+ # burgundy color
    geom_point(data4, aes(.data4[[xvar]], .data4[[zvar]]),
               shape=20, colour="#F0B27A", size=2, show.legend=TRUE)+  #this line is for transients
    labs(x = "Time (s)", y = "Z-Score")+
    ggtitle("Test - Z-score")+
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(Tminus60,Endrec,60), limits = c(Tminus60,NA))+ 
    scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(-3, 6))+
    theme_laura()}
```

To test, I created 4 datasets: (apologies if there are problems with them, I' m not very used to creating datasets since I usually import them)

```
set.seed(123)

MYdata1 <- data.frame(Time = 1:1000,
                    Zscore = rnorm(1000))
MYdata2 <- data.frame(Time = c(167,335,467,678,989),
                    Zscore = c(1,0,1,2,1) ,
                    MYEVENT = "EV1")
MYdata3 <- data.frame(Time = c(101,656,750),
                      Zscore = c(0,0,1) ,
                      MYEVENT = "EV2")
MYdata4 <- data.frame(Time = c(55,66,72,102,150,167,199,230,454,500,555,676,888,999),
                      Amplitude = c(1,0,2,1,0,2,1,2,1,0,2,1,1,1),
                      MYEVENT = "TRANSIENT")
```

But when I enter the variables in the equation using `plot_testassess(MYdata1,MYdata2,MYdata3,MYdata4,Time,Zscore,Amplitude)`

I get the following error

> Error in `geom_point()`:
> ! `mapping` must be created by `aes()`
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Does anybody know what I am doing incorrectly?

**EDIT**

I have been informed in comments that two of my issues were that I was not using the special keyword .data correctly, and that I was not explicitly specifying the attribute type in geom_ . However, with these changes I am encountering a new error:

> Error in enquo(x) : object 'Time' not found
> 7. enquo(x)
> 6. inject(enquo(!!sym(name)), frame)
> 5. arg_enquos("x")
> 4. aes(.data[[xvar]], .data[[yvar]])
> 3. ggplot.default(data = data1, aes(.data[[xvar]], .data[[yvar]]))
> 2. ggplot(data = data1, aes(.data[[xvar]], .data[[yvar]]))
>
> 1. plot_testassess(MYdata1, MYdata2, MYdata3, MYdata4, Time, Zscore,  Amplitude)

I believe this could be because it is interpreting xvar as an object now rather than a column name now, would anybody know why?

Comment: The `geom_*` functions' first argument is the mapping argument, not the data argument, so it thinks you are trying to apply your data as an aesthetic. Best to specify your arguments (i.e. `geom_point(data = data2, ...)`

Comment: `.data` is a special keyword for the data in the current layer. Always use `.data`, not `.data1`, `.data2`, `.data3`... It doesn't matter what your data frame is named, `.data` is the keyword.

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes you both suggested, but now I think it has gone back to expecting 'Time' to be an object, since I am getting the following new  error _Error in enquo(x) : object 'Time' not found_